# c# code but implement on java. Insert IEnumerable method into List

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

Here is the example of code in C#. What I am trying to do is to make the same in java. Overall, I have Enemy class which can create different types of enemies. Every enemy has its own behaviour.

```
// Creating list of behaviours for enemies
private List<IEnumerator<int>> behaviours = new List<IEnumerator<int>>();

// Adding behaviours into list
private void AddBehaviour(IEnumerable<int> behaviour)
{
    behaviours.Add(behaviour.GetEnumerator());
}

public static Enemy CreateSeeker(Vector2 position)
{
    var enemy = new Enemy(Art.Seeker, position);
    enemy.AddBehaviour(enemy.FollowPlayer());

    return enemy;
}
// Method of type IEnumerable<int> to be able to add it to List. This method contains behaviour 
// of enemy. 
IEnumerable<int> FollowPlayer(float acceleration = 1f)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Velocity += (PlayerShip.Instance.Position - Position).ScaleTo(acceleration);
        if (Velocity != Vector2.Zero)
            Orientation = Velocity.ToAngle();
 // yield keyword allows to return function and resume when it will be called one more time.
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

I took this code from this guide: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-neon-vector-shooter-in-xna-more-gameplay--gamedev-10103
And now I am trying to make the same implementation in my java code. But I met some problems. 
I do not really understand how to add method FollowPlayer into a list. And even how should this method look like. Below I show my own implementation. But seems that my game goes into forever loop and everything pauses.

```
// We  will be adding Iterable<Enemy> methods with enemy behaviour into our Iterable<Enemy> type 
ArrayList private ArrayList<Iterator<Enemy>> behaviours = new ArrayList();

private void addBehaviour(Iterable<Enemy> behaviour) {
    behaviours.add(behaviour.iterator());
}

public static Enemy createSeeker(Vector2 position){
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy(AssetLoader.seeker, position);
    enemy.addBehaviour(enemy.followPlayer());
    return enemy;
}

private Iterable<Enemy> followPlayer() {
    while (true) {
        velocity.add(PlayerShip.instance.position.sub(position).scl(acceleration));
        if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
            orientation = velocity.angle();

        Thread.yield();

    }
}
```

I just need help to understand that am I doing wrong and even am going in a right direction. Of course, I could create for every enemy type different class which will contain it behaviour and specifications.
Especially I am not sure about the setting Iterable as return type and how do I use Thread.yield() function. 
I will be grateful for any kind of help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The C# yield operator *is not equivalent* to `Thread.yield()`.  At all.  They have literally nothing whatsoever to do with each other, and Java has no analog to C# yield iterators.

Comment: hm, okey, thanks! So then I will try to implement that just by creating different classes for every type of enemy.